# Error debido a que no me reconocen el archivo Mail

Tags: laravel-5

Veran, tengo en mi proyecto que enviar un mensaje a un usuario.

Este es el código del envio del mensaje:

```
Mail::to($usuario->email)->send(new Dispulpa($usuario->name.' '.$usuario->second_name, $oferta->titulo));
```

Este es el archivo Disculpa.php:

```
<?php

namespace App\Mail;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;

class Disculpa extends Mailable{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;
    public $gesto, $tipo;

    public function __construct($gesto, $tipo){
        $this->gesto=$gesto;
        $this->tipo=$tipo;
    }

    public function build(){
        return $this->view('correo.disculpa');
    }
}
```

Y este el view al que lleva:

```
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Sentimos comunicarle que se cancelo la oferta de trabajo</title>
</head> 
<body>
    <p>La oferta de trabajo de {{$tipo}}, que pidiste en Bolsa Empleo San Fernando se ha eliminado.</p><br>
    <p>Pero no te desanimes, {{$gesto}}, puede que dentro de poco encuentras otra oferta de trabajo</p><br>
    <p>¡Que te vaya bien la proxima vez!</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Pero me veo con esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No se que puede estar fallando. Tengo otro archivo Mail y ese por el contrario si que funciona.

Edito: Añado mis importaciones.

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Mail;
use Validator;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use \App\Oferta;
use \App\Mail\Dispulpa;
use \App\Inscribe;
use \App\User;
```

Comment: Te falta incluir la ubicacion de tu clase `Disculpa` en `OfertaController`

Comment: Así es como lo tengo: use \App\Mail\Dispulpa;

Comment: De hecho, tengo otro fichero Mail llamado Mensajeria.php y ese si lo sustituyo funciona.

Answer (score 0):

Ya logre solucionarlo, aunque es algo extraño:
Lo unico que hice fue crear un nuevo archivo Mail, al cual llame "Llamada.php" y copie el codigo de Disculpa.php dentro, ¡Y listo, al fin logre enviar el email!
A la conclusión que llego es que por algun motivo no le gusta a Laravel que un fichero Mail se llame "Disculpa.php". Antes de probar esto probe de todo, incluyendo copiar el codigo de Disculpa.php en otro Mail que si funciono, lo cual para mi sorpresa tambien servia de "solución".